# jQuery file Upload and getting $_Files

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am using the the jQuery plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload to up load files. I just wanna use the upload button to show the selected files and only upload the files when the form is submitted. following is my code :

```
    <form id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <span class="btn btn-success btn-mini fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files</span>
                    <input  id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                    <button type="submit" id="start_uploads">Start uploads</button>
                </span>
    </form>
```

I can create the list using the following code :

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
                           $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                              //alert('Added file: ' + file.name);
                                 $('<li/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#fileList');
                                            });

                                    },

                                });
```

But when I submit the form I don get anything in $_FILES or var_dump(files); Can anybody please help me out of what am I missing and how I can accomplish this ?
One thing to mention, if I don use the js code for the listing then do get the $_FILES variable having all the selected files.

Comment: Can you post your php code, too, please?

Comment: if(($_FILES))
    var_dump($_FILES);
else echo "Nothing";

Comment: However, U can check the entire code here : http://pastebin.com/BBZLaGJk

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(!empty($_FILES)):?>
    <?php echo json_encode($_FILES);?>
<?php else:?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <!-- Generic page styles -->

            <!-- Bootstrap styles for responsive website layout, supporting different screen sizes -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
            <!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
            <!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
            <!-- Bootstrap Image Gallery styles -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
            <!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <input  id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            <button id="sendFiles">Send</button>
            <ul id="fileList"></ul>   
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    var filesData;
                    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        add: function (e, data) {
                            filesData = data;
                            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                                $('<li/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#fileList');
                            });

                        },
                        done: function (e, data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }

                    });

                    $('#sendFiles').on('click', function () {
                        if (filesData) {
                            filesData.submit();
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </body> 
    </html>
<?php endif;?>
```

Basically, you have to call a method `submit` of the data object in the function `add`. Then you'll get the `data` object which contains `$_FILES` as a json string. And you don't have to use actual form for sending files through this plugin, however you can wrap the input with a form tag (as it was in your code) in order to allow users without JavaScript (do they exist? :)) to also send files.
If you don't want to send files throught JavaScript, then in order to show the file list you don't have to use the plugin. You can get information about the files using FileList [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)